# How to use filter made by Spark AR?

Tags: android-studio, spark-ar-studio

I have made many filters with Spark AR. How can I import it to Android Studio so I can use in my own app?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Spark AR filters are only usable within Facebook, Messenger and Instagram mobile apps.

You could use an a "tryit link" to launch to it from your app.

In Spark AR Hub, under your effect, use the Share button to get the "tryit link":

[image]